# How to open User registration in a pop up?

Tags: users, status-messages

I'm using Fancybox to open user registration page in a pop up window. Here is the code

```
$('.fan_popup').fancybox({
  type: 'iframe',
  href: '/user/registration',
  width: 800,
  padding: 5,
  height: 600
});
```

The pop up window is shown but the page gives message like "You are not authorized to access this page.". How to overcome this.

Answer (score 1):

Probably your server's settings prevent opening registration pages within frames. This prevents embedding your registration form in 3rd party webpage to create spam users et cetera. That is usually a good thing, even if what happens to you is over-restrictive.

Now, why to reinvent the wheel? There is a [Modal forms](https://drupal.org/project/modal_forms) module ready.

> Modal forms make use of the modal feature in the ctools module to open some common forms in a modal window.
>   Supported forms
>
> - Log in (modal_forms/nojs/login)
> - Request new password (modal_forms/nojs/password)
> - **Create new account** (modal_forms/nojs/register)
> - Contact (modal_forms/nojs/contact)
> - Comment (modal_forms/nojs/comment/reply/%node)
> - Webform (modal_forms/nojs/webform/%node)

*Emphasis mine.*

It has some bugs, but for first 3 it works pretty well. Or at least it used to.